Has any country managed to enforce VPN fines (or other punishments related to VPN use) to a signficant degree?
Reportedly Twitter/X has been subject to a "complete suspension" in Brazil, following a Supreme Court order there. But the part I want to ask about is this:

People attempting to access the platform after the ban through VPNs could be fined R$50,000 (£6.7k), according to local media reports.

Has any country managed to enforce such VPN (Virtual Private Network) restrictions/punishments though, to a signficant degree?
(I'm asking because e.g. RFERL recommends VPNs as a way to bypass censorship in Russia etc. The US government even funds some such services [according to RFERL]. So, the expectation is presumably that VPN users aren't easy to find and punish. Even more so if it's not a blanket ban all such VPNs, as in the quote.)

Please spell out acronyms at least one. Also, a brief explanation of what a VPN is and why a state might sanction it would be in order for readers not familiar with this corner of Internet technology.

Your question about enforcing VPN restrictions is implicitly premised on the assumption that such legal restrictions (as opposed to merely technical ones at ISP level) exist somewhere other than Brazil. Do they?

@Greendrake Pretty sure that China has them.

@ohwilleke I did search about them in China and only found technical but not legal restrictions. Maybe missed something though.

Can't these countries block VPN connections instead of fining their use? On the other hand it probably is sufficient if people think that they could be found out to have an effect. And the significant degree can only be answered if it would be known how many people use these services, but that is typically not known or is it?

Actually it is any access to X which is fined (usage of VPN is not special in this regard). Newsmakers just created another hoax.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution In Brazil right now, accessing X formerly known as Twitter will get you a fine. Using VPN for other purposes is legal. For technical reasons, it should not be possible in Brazil to access X without VPN but it would be technically possible to access the US site with VPN. The access is illegal, not the use of VPN.

@Greendrake "it is a crime to use a VPN in China." https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=65068

@ohwilleke "Crime" appears to be an exaggeration. ChatGPT now tells me it's only an administrative offence which is not clear cut in any legislation but is rather how the authorities interpret various Internet regulations.

@gnasher729 But if the only way to access X is with a VPN, using a VPN to access X is a crime. More generally, using a VPN to get around access restrictions is a crime.
